# Empathy indicator missing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, empathy

I use Gnome Desktop Environment on Ubuntu 16.04. Empathy does not display any icons on my status / indicator panel. Is this a normal behavior or do I have something mis-configured?

Comment: Have you installed Empathy? According to this [news article](https://www.linux.com/news/ubuntu-1604-drops-brasero-and-empathy-gnome-calendar-be-adopted), Ubuntu has dropped Empathy from the default install as of 16.04.